# Nautilus won't connect to SFTP share

Tags: nautilus, 17.04, sftp

I updated from 16.10 to 17.04 and suddenly Nautilus no longer connects to my SFTP share. It worked before on 16.10 so it's a mystery to me. Nautilus now just shows:

> Oops! Something went wrong.
>   Don't have permission to access the requested location.

Please help me debug/fix this issue.

Comment: can you connect from comandline?

Comment: With just sftp or ssh, yes.

Comment: I pretty much solved this by moving to Kubuntu and Dolphin. It was a deal-breaker for me and the error message was as useless as the common Windows' `Something happened`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pretty much solved this by moving to Kubuntu and Dolphin. It was a deal-breaker for me and the error message was as useless as the common Windows' Something happened.